# Array data from ng-repeat in multiple columns and rows, how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array list in my hand, I want to show this array listi with the ng-repeat as in the image.
What's the right way to do this?

I want to do the following if possible, there are "+" on the four sides of the box. When I click on "+", in which way I click on it, I want new boxes to be created in that direction as much as the number of boxes under it. The other option is the delete icon in each box. I want that box erased when I click on them.

I want the visual in the image.

[image]

```
vm.sections = {
    width: 3,
    matrix: [
      { name: "Left Text", position: "left" },
      { name: "Top Text", position: "top" },
      { name: "Right Text", position: "right" },
      { name: "Left Text", position: "left" },
      { name: "Center", position: "center" },
      { name: "Right Text", position: "right" },
      { name: "Left Text", position: "left" },
      { name: "Bottom Text", position: "bottom" },
      { name: "Bottom Text", position: "bottom" }
    ]
};
```

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="row" ng-if="(section.position==='top' || section.position==='bottom' || section.position==='center')"
             ng-repeat="section in sections.matrix track by $index">
          <div class="cell section"
               ng-repeat="section in sections.matrix track by $index">
            {{ section.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unlike some sites, this is not really an appropriate forum to ask for others to just write code for you. Typically we like to see that you've made an effort to write the code and there's just one or two issues that you're not able to resolve. Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] to get an idea of how to create a post that is likely to generate one or more good answers.

Comment: You're right, I did a sample for my array list and ng-repeat, but it wasn't repeat like in the image.